# How do I position an element with respect to another element

Tags: html, css, xpath

In the below code, I want the button and the facebook share link to be placed underneath the `<span>` element, but the button should be exactly in the center below the `<span>` element. As both the `facebook` share and the button are enclosed in a `<div>` tag, how do I refer to the `<span>` element from the `<button>` element so that the button is placed in the center with respect to the `<span>` element. The share link should be in the left most corner from the button, but in the same row.

```html
<body id="page-background">
    <div class="background" id="page">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="quote" class="well position-message quote-shape">
     <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
          <div id="share" class="col text-left">
                  <a class="click" href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={{fbapp_id}}&link={{link_url}}&message={{share_message|urlencode}}&display=popup&redirect_uri={{link_url}}" target="_blank">
                   <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i> Share
                  </a>
                </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
                    <button type="button" id="click" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-circle button-shape">
            <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Below is a snap of my page

[image: QUotePageSnap]

Comment: What do you mean? Xpath is not used to place elements into a model, it is used to fetch elements from a model.

Comment: thank you @AlexeyR. I was confused a bit. Is there anyway to place the button in the center below the 1<span>` element?

Comment: Basically that depends on what framework you use for building your html and at what moment you need to put your button there. This could be also achieved by running javascript code on client side that would insert a node into a particular node of your DOM.

Comment: I have added the snap shot of my page. I want the button to be in the center

Comment: you need to post your CSS code

Answer (score 1):

If you know the width of all of your elements you can do this using margin, setting an inverse margin in relation to the width of your share
link and span width.

If you don’t know the widths or the page is dynamic you can use JavaScript/jQuery. Save the elements to variables, get their widths, and then do the same math you would do as if they were static widths.

Static example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EoLWZY

```
<style>
#page{
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
width: 600px;
padding: 20px;
}
#emptySpan{
display: block;
width: 500px;
height: 50px;
background-color: yellow;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
line-height: 45px;
}
.row{
text-align: center;
}
#share{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute
background-color: red;
width: 50px;
float:left;
}
#click{
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
margin: 10px -150px;
}
</style>

<body id="page-background">
<div class="background" id="page"> 
<div class="container-fluid">
<div id="quote" class="well position-message quote-shape">
    <span id="emptySpan">empty span</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="share" class="col text-left">
  <a class="click" href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={{fbapp_id}}&link={{link_url}}&message={{share_message|urlencode}}&display=popup&redirect_uri={{link_url}}" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i>Share</a> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
<button type="button" id="click" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-circle button-shape">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-2x">Button CTA</i>
</button>
</div> 
</div>
</div>  
</div>
</body>
```